# sed and the odyssey of escaping a bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables, sed, escaping

Having

```
DEST_PATH='/var/www/clones'
site='xyz.com'

sed -i -e "s/\$log_path\s=\s'\(.*\)'/\$log_path = '$DEST_PATH\/$site\/logs'/" $DEST_PATH/$site/configuration.php
```

The problem is the forward slashes in first variable, because this is what is being processed and returns error:

```
sed -i -e "s/\$log_path\s=\s'\(.*\)'/\$log_path = '/var/www/clones\/xyz.com\/logs'/"  configuration.php
```

When this is what actually should be run:

```
sed -i -e "s/\$log_path\s=\s'\(.*\)'/\$log_path = '\/var\/www\/clones\/xyz.com\/logs'/"  configuration.php
```

So I know, I could replace all the `/` inside `$DEST_PATH`, and run the `sed` again, but I was wondering if you know or can think of any other/better way of doing so. Ideally, maybe having `sed` automatically escape the `'$DEST_PATH/$site/logs'` if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a modern enough version of `sed` (e.g., GNU `sed`)?  Then you are not required to use `/` to separate pattern and substitution.  Any character will do.

E.g., you can use

```
s,pattern,substitution,
```

instead of

```
s/pattern/substitution/
```

Comment: 4.2.2 is the version I use

Comment: GNU version 4.2.2?  Go ahead with `,` as I suggest in my answer, then!

Comment: Fixed it... I was missing a `,`